# Writing integral in terms of distributions

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

EDIT (*now asking how to write $F$ as distributions, instead of writing the integral in terms of distributions*):

Let $F$ be the distribution defined by its action on a test function $\phi$ as

\begin{equation*}
F(\phi)=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}x\phi(x)dx.
\end{equation*}

How would you write $F$ in terms of the delta distribution, heaviside distribution, and a regular distribution $R$ defined by its action on a test function $\phi$ as

\begin{equation*}
R(\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\phi(x)dx
\end{equation*}

for a continuous function $g$?

Edit: Q1)b) in this link https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/legacy/3422/B5a_13.pdf

Comment: I have a strong feeling that there is no such continuous function $g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suspect one could not find continuous $g(x)$.
I state that $g(x) = x\cdot H(x-\pi)\cdot H(2\pi-x)$. Namely $g(x) = x$ if $x\in[\pi, 2\pi]$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\in R\setminus [\pi, 2\pi]$. So
$$
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}x\phi(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)\phi(x)dx.
$$

Comment: $g$ needs to be continuous though... If I write $g(x)=x, x>0; g(x) = 0, x<0$ then I feel it might help but I get $\int_{\pi}^{\infty}x\phi(x)dx$, for example, as one of the terms, and I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: I think @NikitaEvseev's rewrite is a very natural choice. user152440, what do you mean "$g$ _needs_ to be continuous"? In what sense "needs"?

Comment: The question I've been given specifies it

Answer (score 1):

Although I think @NikitaEvseev's answer is the most natural, perhaps the small exercise of rewriting integration over an interval $[a,b]$ as a distribution is worthwhile. That is, consider
$$
u(\varphi) \;=\; \int_a^b \varphi(x)\;dx
$$
Edit: simpler than what I wrote before:
$$
u(\varphi) \;=\; \int_a^b \varphi(x)\,dx
\;=\; \int_{-\infty}^\infty (H(x-a) - H(x-b))\cdot \varphi(x)\;dx
$$
That is, if *translates* and reflections of the Heaviside function are allowed, then it's just this (with $\varphi(x)$ replaced by $x\cdot \varphi(x)$).

But then I'm confused as to why the posing of the question in the linked-to source made it seem as though something more complicated should happen.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit unsure - since a distribution is defined in terms of its action on a test function then it doesn't really seem to make sense to have derivatives of test functions in the answer as then this can't be written purely in terms of distributions

Comment: I think it should be $H(x-a) - H(x-b)$ (not $H(x-a) - H(b-x)$). Or in another way $H(x-a)\cdot H(b-x)$.

Comment: If I let $F$ be the distribution defined by its action on a test function $\phi$ as $F(\phi)= \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} x\cdot \phi(x)dx$ then I think I'm supposed to write $F$ in terms of distributions (I worded the question badly saying to write the integral in terms of distributions). But then having $x \cdot \phi$ in the integral in the answer doesn't allow me to do this as it needs to act only on $\phi$

Comment: @NikitaEvseev, oops, yes, thanks.