# distributions and their actions

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

I have question,

Each of the following distributions is defined by its action. Identify the
generalized function for each of them

a) $B_a(\phi)=a^2 \phi(a)$

b) $B_b= -e^{-b}(\phi(b)+\phi^{'}(b))$

c) $B_c= \int_{a}^{b} x^2 \phi(x)dx$

For part a) I know that since a distribution has form $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \phi(x)dx$, $f(x)$ must be $x^2 \delta (x-a)$ So that's the generalized function. But is f(x) the generalized function or is the distribution the generalized function?

I know what the answers are supposed to be.

for c) the answer is $H(x-a)(1-H(x-b))x^2$
Edit: A little search yielded this : [Writing integral in terms of distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289868/writing-integral-in-terms-of-distributions) and Nikita's comment has been most helpful

I'd appreciate knowing why Paul's answer is also correct would appreciate more understanding how to do part b

Answer (score 1):

Paul seems to use the following equalities:
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[a,b]}(x) \, f(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (H(x-a)-H(x-b)) \, f(x) \, dx
,
$$
where $\chi_A$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$ and $H$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

---

If $a<b$ then
$$
H(x-a) = \begin{cases}
0 & (x<a) \\
1 & (x>a) \\
\end{cases}
= \begin{cases}
0 & (x<a) \\
1 & (a<x<b) \\
1 & (b<x) \\
\end{cases}
\\
H(x-b) = \begin{cases}
0 & (x<b) \\
1 & (x>b) \\
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
0 & (x<a) \\
0 & (a<x<b) \\
1 & (b<x) \\
\end{cases}
$$
Thus,
$$
H(x-a)-H(x-b)
= \begin{cases}
0-0=0 & (x<a) \\
1-0=1 & (a<x<b) \\
1-1=0 & (b<x) \\
\end{cases}
$$
i.e.
$
H(x-a)-H(x-b) = \chi_{[a,b]}(x)
$
modulo values at the end points, where it doesn't really matter when integrating.

Comment: care to explain the second equality?

Comment: @Jama. Explication has been added to the post.